# feImage xlink:href svg source is blurry compared to png

Tags: svg, svg-filters

When using `<feImage xlink:href=""/>` to include an image which will be used like the photoshop `multiply` filter, I have found if I include an svg the edges are blurry, but when using a png the edges are sharp.

Taking the following code:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 540 610" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <filter id="myFilter_1">
      <feImage xlink:href="./shape.png" x="0" y="0" width="470" height="470"/>
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" mode="multiply"/>
    </filter>
    <filter id="myFilter_2">
      <feImage xlink:href="./shape.svg" x="0" y="0" width="470" height="470"/>
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" mode="multiply"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <image style="filter:url(#myFilter_1);" x="0" y="0" width="540" height="610" xlink:href="./myimage.png"/>
  <image style="filter:url(#myFilter_2);" x="0" y="0" width="540" height="610" xlink:href="./myimage.png"/>
</svg>
```

`#myFilter_2` is blurry compared to `#myFilter_1`

My `shape.svg` is a rectangle rotated 45deg.
I have tried both
`<polygon id="pink-triangle" points="270,0 540,270 270,540 0,270" fill="#db0962"/>`
and
`<g id="pink-triangle2" transform="rotate(45 270 270)">
    <rect x="80" y="80" width="380" height="380" fill="#db0962"/>
  </g>`

Why is this? Am I missing some attribute?

Comment: Please post shape.svg and shape.png